# If $A$ and $B$ are rings with unity, prove that $U(A \times B) \cong U(A) \times U(B)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> If $A$ and $B$ are rings with unity, prove that the group of units $U(A \times B)$ of the direct product $A \times B$ is isomorphic to the direct product $U(A) \times U(B)$ of the respective groups of units.

I have a problem when I try to define the function, because I don't understand how it works.

I think $f\colon U(A \times B) \to U(A) \times U(B)$ should be $f((a,b)) = (a,b)$, where $(a,b) \in U(A \times B)$.

Comment: Sorry, is direct product.

Comment: So what (do you think) is the problem with this definition?

Comment: How can i sure $a$ is a element of $U(A)$ and $b$ is a element of $U(B)$ ?

Comment: You've taken $(a, b) \in U(A \times B)$. What does it mean for $(a, b)$ to be a unit in $A \times B$? What does that imply about $a \in A$ and $b \in B$? It's all right there, you just need to apply the definitions (of unit, direct product, etc.).

Comment: Ahhh i need to apply the definitions.. Thankyou c: